# HashMap tree imitation duplicate key problem

Tags: java

I have a simple code that takes an int and then a number that is attached to that number like a tree and a child. The thing is that the hashmap cant take 2 values attached to one key and just want to see if anyone has any ideas on how to fix it.

Basically imagine you have a matrix 0000, and you input 1 (the row or the number the value is connected to) and 3(to the index of the matrix that will be filled) so it should return 0010

Here is the code

```
Map<Integer,Integer> numberInput = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
      numberInput.put(1,2);
      numberInput.put(1,9);
      numberInput.put(2,3);
      numberInput.put(7,8);
      int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];
      for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length;i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length + 1;j++){
                  if(numberInput.get(i) != null){
                       if(j  == numberInput.get(i)){
                           matrix[i-1][j-1] = 1;
                       }
                  }
          }
      }
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length;i ++){
        for(int j = 0; j < matrix.length;j++){
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Why have you tagged three languages?

Comment: mb @tgdavies fixed it

Comment: Please edit your question to explain what you want to happen when there are two values for one key.

Comment: You could use a `Map<Integer, Set<Integer>>` instead of a `Map<Integer, Integer>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are trying to put two values (2 and 9) with the same key (1), but the HashMap will only keep the last value (9) for the key 1.

If you want to represent a tree-like structure with multiple children for each node, using a HashMap directly may not be suitable. Instead, you can use a different data structure to represent the tree. One approach could be to use a HashMap with Integer as keys and Lists of Integers as values, where each key represents a node, and the list contains all its child nodes.

You can do it like this

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> numberInput = new HashMap<>();
numberInput.put(1, new ArrayList<>());
numberInput.get(1).add(2);
numberInput.get(1).add(9);
numberInput.put(2, new ArrayList<>());
numberInput.get(2).add(3);
numberInput.put(7, new ArrayList<>());
numberInput.get(7).add(8);

int[][] matrix = new int[10][10];
for (int i = 1; i <= matrix.length; i++) {
    List<Integer> children = numberInput.get(i);
    if (children != null) {
        for (int j : children) {
            matrix[i - 1][j - 1] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Small improvement on the initialization: you can use `put(1, List.of(2, 9))`, `put(2, List.of(3))` and `put(7, List.of(8))` if these lists can be read-only.

Comment: @RobSpoor I think `Set` would be a better fit, as OP doesn't seem to care about collection order or duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

I think the flaw is with your approach. The key of the Hashmap should be the location in your Matrix because that will be unique.

If we are using locations in serial i.e. (1,1) is referred as 1, and (1,2) is referred as 2 and (2,1) is referred as 3 than we can use location as key.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> numberInput = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
  numberInput.put(2,1);
  numberInput.put(9,1);
  numberInput.put(3,2);
  numberInput.put(8,7);
```

If we are setting in accurate fashion of matrix i.e. (2,1) = 3, we can use (2,1) as string

```
Map<String,Integer> numberInput = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  numberInput.put("2,1",1);
  numberInput.put("2,2",1);
```

This way is more efficient and you will be able to fetch values by location.
Moreover, if you pass a duplicate key it will "update" the value, which make sense for the case.

Comment: What if we want to set (2,1) and (2,2)?

Comment: If we are setting in accurate fashion of matrix i.e. (2,1) = 3, we can use (2,1) as string.

If we are using locations in serial i.e. (1,1) is referred as 1,  and (1,2) is referred as 2 and (2,1) is referred as 3. Than just use the integer as key. 
My point is that we should use location as key.

Comment: Good idea, it's just that that isn't what your first code sample does.